# jQuery assigning value to array giving error Undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm assigning values to array in forloop But it gives an error that array variable is undefine. following is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#SubmitBtn").live('click',function(){

        var cnt = $("#TotalCnt").val();
        var data = [];

        for(var i=1; i<=cnt; i++)
        {
           var fname = $('#fname_'+i).val();
           var lname = $('#lname_'+i).val();
           var address = $('#address_'+i).val();

           data[i]["fname"] = fname;
           data[i]["lname"] = lname;
           data[i]["address"] = address;
        }

   });

});
```

when I'm assigning value to array it gives error **"data[i] is undefined"**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which jQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create an empty object first, because initially `data[i]` is `undefined`. And undefined does not contains any property under it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#SubmitBtn").live('click',function(){

        var cnt = $("#TotalCnt").val();
        var data = [];

        for(var i=1; i<=cnt; i++)
        {
           var fname = $('#fname_'+i).val();
           var lname = $('#lname_'+i).val();
           var address = $('#address_'+i).val();
           data[i] = {};
           data[i]["fname"] = fname;
           data[i]["lname"] = lname;
           data[i]["address"] = address;
        }

   });

});
```